# django filter() queryset issue

Tags: python, django

I want to show only specific cards, related with specific post:

## UPDATE:

Current issue:

```
Internal Server Error: /board/table/card/create/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\excepti
on.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback? You're calling `.split()` somewhere, but it's not in the code you presented.

Comment: I editet my issue.

Comment: Can you please post your `create_card()` function? Your error cannot find a Board object with the title_board variable you are passing here: `unique_board = Board.objects.get(title=title_board)`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/WVP2U14y I fight with it since 4h...

Comment: Are you sure a Board exists with EXACTLY whatever title you are passing in your request?

Comment: If we delete from views.py lines:  cards = board.cards context = {'cards': cards}, everything works.

Answer (score 0):

You can access directly your cards by doing `board.cards`

```
def board_detail(request, slug):
    board = get_object_or_404(Board, title=slug)
    cards = board.cards
    # ___________^

    template = 'board/board_detail.html'
    context = {'board': board, 'cards': cards}

    return render(request, template, context)
```

And then in your template:

```
{% for card in cards %}
    <p>{{ card.title_card }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I try it, but when I trying again add new card I got: Not Found: /board/table/card/create/ issue. This is valid. First post is valid, next no

Comment: I'm add ".all " but I can't send new form. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 0):

Why access the model manager of cards? If you only want the cards for that board, try board.cards. And you can filter that further